# Return the entered data in a form if the error array is empty

Tags: php

i have this code

first file is a form that gets data and perform some basic email validation
second file gets all data and performs php validation and returns error messages that are stored in an array if the  user inputs something wrong.

my question is that how can i display the contents of the form if there is no errors and the error array is empty.

```
<?php
$error = $_GET['message'];


?>

<html>

      <head>

      <title>Form Validation</title>

      <script type="text/javascript">

             function validateEmail()

      {

         var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
         var reEmail = document.getElementById('reEmail').value;

         atpos = email.indexOf("@");

         dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");



         if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 

         {

            alert("Please enter correct email")

            document.getElementById('email').focus() ;


            return false;

         }

         if (email === reEmail){
            return true;
         }
         alert("emails don't match!");
         return false;





      }
      </script>

    </head>

      <body>

     <div>
         <?php

         if ($error == ""){

         }
         else{
            foreach ($error as $key => $value) {
               echo "<h1>". $value . "</h1>";


            }

         } 

         ?>
      </div>


      <form action="registerExec.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validateEmail());">

         <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">

            <tr>

               <td align="right">Name</td>

               <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

               <td align="right">Email</td>

               <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

               <td align="right">Retype Email</td>

               <td><input type="text" name="reEmail" id="reEmail" /></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

               <td align="right">Zip Code</td>

               <td><input type="text" name="zip" /></td>

            </tr>

             <tr>

               <td align="right">Country</td>

               <td>

                  <select name="country">

                     <option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>

                     <option value="1">USA</option>

                     <option value="2">UK</option>

                     <option value="3">INDIA</option>

                  </select>

               </td>

            </tr>

             <tr>

               <td align="right"></td>

               <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

            </tr>

            </table>

      </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

second file:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = array(" ");
$goodjob = 'goodjob';

if ($email == "" || $zip == "" || $name ==""){

    array_push($message, "Email, Zip, Name should not be empty!");
    // chedk if any of these fields is empty

}

if ($name != ""){
        if (is_numeric($name)) {
            array_push($message, "don't include numberss in name");

        }
    }

if (is_numeric ($zip) ){


} else {
    array_push($message, "zip is not a number!");
}

if (strlen($zip) != 5){
    array_push($message, "Wrong Zip!");
}



$finalmessage =  http_build_query(array('message' => $message));
header("Location: http://localhost/register/classexercise.php?".$finalmessage);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this, let me know if you are expecting something else.

```
    <?php
$error = $_GET['message'];
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function validateEmail(){
     var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
     var reEmail = document.getElementById('reEmail').value;
     atpos = email.indexOf("@");
     dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");

     if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
     {
        alert("Please enter correct email")
        document.getElementById('email').focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     if (email === reEmail){
        return true;
     }
     alert("emails don't match!");
     return false;
  }
  </script>

</head>
  <body>

  <div>
     <?php
     if ($error == ""){
     }
     else{
        foreach ($error as $key => $value) {
           echo "<h1>". $value . "</h1>";
        }
     } 

     ?>
     </div>

  <form action="registerExec.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validateEmail());">

     <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Name</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td align="right">Email</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td align="right">Retype Email</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="reEmail" id="reEmail" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td align="right">Zip Code</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="zip" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right">Country</td>
           <td>
              <select name="country">
                 <option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
                 <option value="1">USA</option>
                 <option value="2">UK</option>
                 <option value="3">INDIA</option>
              </select>
           </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right"></td>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your PHP to display the form content -

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
$message = array();
$goodjob = 'goodjob';

if ($email == "" || $zip == "" || $name ==""){

    array_push($message, "Email, Zip, Name should not be empty!");
    // chedk if any of these fields is empty
}

if ($name != ""){
        if (is_numeric($name)) {
            array_push($message, "don't include numberss in name");
        }
    }

if (!is_numeric ($zip)){
    array_push($message, "zip is not a number!");
}

if (strlen($zip) != 5){
    array_push($message, "Wrong Zip!");
}

if (empty($message)){
    array_push($message, $name);
    array_push($message, $email);
    array_push($message, $zip);
    $finalmessage =  http_build_query(array('message' => $message));
    header("Location: index.php?".$finalmessage);
} else {
    $finalmessage =  http_build_query(array('message' => $message));
    header("Location: index.php?".$finalmessage);
}
?>
```

Comment: as you can see my code is returning the array with the type of errors.

Comment: the question is how do i return the contents if it's empty using the same method of rideriction

Comment: meaning if there are no errors another string is redirected or an array that has the form contents